# How can I run an rsync demon in the private machine?

Tags: rsync

I have never used `rsync` before.

Suppose I have the following two machines:

[image]

I have to run `rsync` with a Python script in Machine-B so that it can periodically fetch new files from Machine-A to Machine-B.

How can I do that?

I mean, how to get started with?

Comment: "_I have never used rsync before_" - there are many questions and answers on this site that deal with `rsync`. Take a look at the simpler ones

Comment: Firstly you'd need the daemon running on the machine you're trying to get the data of, so on Machine-A; secondly you **really** **don't** want to use `rsyncd` on a publicly accessible network - it's meant for use on private networks as it offers no encryption out of the box.